# Cannot make ORB_SLAM2 work with TUM rosbag files

Tags: ros, bagfile, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am running ORB_SLAM2 on one of the ROS bag files from TUM benchmark datasets (rgbd_dataset_freiburg2_pioneer_slam.bag )

What I am seeing on Map Viewer is a increasing number of "blue camera" in the same position.
The Map Viewer is not showing any point cloud data...

ORB-SLAM2:Current Frame Window looks fine though. I see a bunch of ORB feature extracts/disappears as the frame changes. Besides, I confirmed that ORB-SLAM2 worked pretty well with the same dataset when ROS was not involved in. (just rgb + depth image sequence as input sequence) But, I have no luck with this rosbag file...

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here ?
My launch file is attached below

```
<launch>    
    <node name="RGBD" pkg="ORB_SLAM2" type="RGBD" output="screen" args="/home/hankm/OpenSW/ORB_SLAM2/Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt /home/hankm/OpenSW/ORB_SLAM2/Examples/RGB-D/TUM1.yaml">
    
        <remap from="camera/depth_registered/image_raw"     to="camera/depth/image"/>
        <remap from="camera/rgb/image_raw"                  to="camera/rgb/image_color"/>       
    </node>
</launch>
```

rosbag play rgbd_dataset_freiburg2_pioneer_slam.bag followed by the launch file above

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284909/cannot-make-orb_slam2-work-with-tum-rosbag-files/) by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-03-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

change DepthMapFactor parameter in yalm file

DepthMapFactor: 1

fixed this problem

---

Originally posted by [thezest](https://answers.ros.org/users/33702/thezest/) with karma: 38 on 2018-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1